# Can you please tell me why I'm getting this error message on solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

from solidity:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
  --> contracts/MySimpleStorage.sol:16:5:
   |
16 |     people[] public people;
   |   
Note: The previous declaration is here:
  --> contracts/MySimpleStorage.sol:11:5:
   |
11 |     struct people {
   |     (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

error 2

from solidity:

```
TypeError: Expected callable expression before call options.
   contracts/MySimpleStorage.sol:32:21:
   |
32 |         people.push(people{favoriteNumber: _favoriteNumber, name: _name});
```

[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSU0Y.png)

**here's the main code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract MySimpleStorage {

    //this will get initilized to 0 since we did not state the number
    uint256 public favoriteNumber;
    bool favoriteBool;

    struct people{
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;
    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;

    }

    
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{
        people.push(people(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: yes please...check the code below

Comment: Copy and paste all your smart code into your question. Not post only an image because it's difficult to understand the errors

Comment: contract Storage {
    struct people{
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;
    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;

    }

    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{
        people.push(people(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

You are facing errors because of few the below-mentioned errors:

1. from solidity: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.

- you declared the struct as (lowercase - people) - `struct people{`
- but used it as ( uppercase - People[] ) - `People[] public people;`

The aforementioned `people` is already declared in a struct, and you are again declaring `people` as an array name.

Instead, it should be:

```
struct People{ 
   People[] public people;
```

because in Solidity, struct names are typically capitalized as per the common naming conventions.
So `people` is declared as a public array of type `People[]`.

2. from solidity:

   TypeError: Expected callable expression before call options

It is due to a missing bracket in the below statement:
`people.push(people{favoriteNumber: _favoriteNumber, name: _name});`

Instead, it should be:
`people.push(`**`people(`**`{favoriteNumber: _favoriteNumber, name: _name}`**`)`**`);`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is from case sensitivity. you have declared struct with lower case here -struct people
You will need to declare same before the dynamic array here-People[]
Lowercase here is your object name that appears on the button in public, and this could be anything -public people
Bottonname.push(structNAME...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).